# Use same slide number on several slides in keynote?

Tags: keynote

As you might know, you can add some notes for every slide in Keynote. Since I want to talk quite a lot about one specific slide, there are a lot of notes I want to add to this slide. In the moderator view, I can view this notes, but since they are so long, I would have to scroll if I place them all on one slide.

So my idea was to copy the slide lets say five times and put a portion of my notes on every of the copies. Then, I can "click through my notes" while the slide looks similar all the time. The only problem is, that if I do so, the slide has five different slide numbers.

Is there a way to set the number of  a slide or any other way to solve this? Thank you!

Comment: Are you required to number your slides? I always found this to be distracting and space-consuming. If you don't number your slides, you (obviously) won't have this problem.

Comment: +1: I often want to do this because I like to keep track of the number of slides I have for timing purposes, but often I make step-by-step animations using several slides, which should really only be counted as one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is an option for this. So you will have to manually number *all* slides in order to keep the slide/page number the same for several of them.

Comment: I feared it... so I hope there will be some more answers telling the opposite :-)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the answer is to resize the notes display in the Presenter View. If you can get your notes to fit comfortably in Presenter View, then there is little need for duplicating the slides.

Try the following:

1. In Keynote, select "Play -> Customize Presenter Display". You'll be presented with a flexible layout and and an Inspector
2. In the inspector, assure that "Notes" is checked.
3. Try resizing the "Notes" display so that it is large enough to view all (or most) of your notes. (You can have only the notes displayed if you like.)

Everything on the Presenter display is moveable, so try editing all the elements to suit your needs.